# Copying the selection and later pasting it

Tags: excel, vba

I need to store the selected cells and use their values in future. I am storing the the selection to a variable of range object and then i am modifying the selected cells. I am checking the results in other subroutine and if condition is false then i need to restore the values on the same range as it was previously.

```
Public hi, hj As Integer

Public ActSheet As Worksheet

Public SelRange As Range

Sub per_num()


Dim cell As Object

Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
Set SelRange = Selection
SelRange.Copy



For Each cell In Selection

    'perform some action

Next cell

hi = Selection.Row
hj = Selection.Column


End Sub

  Sub num_per()
     if something is false
     Cells(hi, hj).Select
     SelRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your range creates a reference to that group of cells. What you are asking requires you to write the values into memory. This should do what you are asking:

```
Option Explicit

Public selArray As Variant    ' Add this global variable
Public SelRange As Range

Sub per_num()

Dim cell As Range
Set SelRange = Selection
selArray = SelRange    ' Returns the values from your range into a variant

For Each cell In Selection
    'perform some action
Next cell

End Sub

Sub num_per()
   ' if something is false
   SelRange = selArray     ' Writes the values from the variant back into the range
   Set SelRange = Nothing
   If IsArray(selArray) Then Erase selArray
End Sub
```

In the per_num sub, it creates the reference to your selection and writes the values into the selArray variable.

In the num_per sub it writes the values back into the cells referred to by your range.

*It is worth noting that selArray won't actually be an array if you have only selected one cell, the naming was just a hangover from my initial attempt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...can you please clear the concept little bit more, as VBA is object oriented and by defining an object of the same type(var1) and making it equal to same type of variable means object type(var2).. copies all the values in the defining variable(var1). So why this is not happening here. or vba is  not exactly object oreiented..

Comment: As far as I understand it, and I could be corrected on this, it is because the default property of the Range object is .Value so when you make the Variant equal to the Range it is not making it the same object type (the reference to .Range is equivalent to .Range.Value - In the case of a single cell, it returns the value, if multiple cells are selected it returns an array of values).